# negative value format using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have dynamic value populating from database to xml file. And I used below format to format the number.

xsl:with-param name="input" select="format-number(lsp:HitorMissSalesAMount,'00000000.00')"/>"

and if the amount in the xml file is 2345.00 it is populating as 2345.00 but if the amount is -ve like -2.0 it is populating as -00000002.00 but I want it as -2.0. Can somebody help me on this.

This is happening only to convert to text file but if I convert to csv it is showing correctly(-2.0). Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this expression instead...

```
<xsl:with-param name="input" select="format-number(lsp:HitorMissSalesAMount,'#0.00')"/>"
```

The # should not display any leading zeroes in this case.